# is it possible that by clicking, the class of the element change?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a switch for my website that when you click it the language of the page change. Yesterday I saw a close live example in a website.

Here's the link: http://iranfilm76.com/

The object on the left side in the header is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but instead of changing the background i want to change the language.

I already have the functions for changing the language, my problem is the object, I download the image and css for the file.

I take a close look at the codes with firebug and when you click on the tag the class of the tag changes to `class="changestyle"`.

How can I do this? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: How do you change the language? Script?

Comment: @ Karthikeyan: yep...

Comment: `$("your element").click(function (){$(this).toggleClass("changestyle");});`

Comment: You can use JQuery's .removeClass() / .toggleClass() / .addClass()

Comment: @user1394628 - No one says OP wants jQuery.

Comment: the tag already have a class should i first remove it and then add it or when i add it the class remove itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
YOUR_ELEMENT.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("changestyle");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/KpwkG/ | http://jsfiddle.net/WsGGa

Comment: is it JQuery or javascript?

Comment: This is pure JavaScript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WsGGa/ For an example of this working as straight javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For a non pure javascript approach, you can try selecting your toggle element using jquery like so:

```
$('element').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('language');
});
```

Then in your CSS you can apply whatever rules you want

Comment: Why are you using jQuery?

Comment: From the [tag:javascript] tag description: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: I could still see it as a valid answer - but there should at least be some comment included about it requiring more than just the straight javascript requested.